# Correct bootstrap spacing and margins - Top portion of section is partially missing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Theme template: [Porto](https://portotheme.com/html/porto/9.1.0/demo-digital-agency-2-dark-our-work.html) (The work items on the right are aligned with the top of the viewable portion of the page). when selecting 'view all' on the left menu.

Site using the above template:  [DMMBlitz](https://dmmblitz.com/our-work) (The work items on the right are **NOT aligned** with the top of the viewable portion of the page), when selecting 'view all' on the left menu.

I've looked through https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/ and tried about every single combination there is.

But I can't get a site to apply the correct spacing to the right slider work items as it is on the template, even though the bootstrap spacing appears to be the same.

What bootstrap spacing is required to fix this, and apply the correct spacing to the right side page items so it's spaced on the DMMBlitz site as per the template in use?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `data-hash-offset="100"` rather than `data-hash-offset-lg="100"` on view all `<a>` tag, may be it works.

Comment: Thx, but unfortunately not.